# Extracting ticker symbols from file

Tags: awk, sed

The following three lines are an extract from a large text file:

```
9       40        0.5752        2        0.0000        *BRK.B:23.42:24.08:-2.82%        PFE:28.05:26.94:3.97%
9       40        0.5752        2        0.0000        *NOV:23.42:24.08:-2.82%
3       50        0.5752        7        0.0000        C:23.42:24.08:-2.82%             *AAPL:28.05:26.94:3.97%%       *MMM:28.05:26.94:3.97%
```

I wish to extract just the ticker symbols into a single column so I get:

```
BRK.B
PFE
C
AAPL
MMM
NOV
```

I have tried using a combination of sed and awk but can't seem to allow for optional tickers on the same row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the specific example, this works:

```
$ grep -o '[[:upper:]][[:upper:].]*' infile
BRK.B
PFE
NOV
C
AAPL
MMM
```

I.e., any uppercase character, optionally followed by a sequence of periods or uppercase characters. `-o` extracts just the matches, one per output line.

Answer (score 1):

***grep*** approach:

```
grep -Po '[[:upper:]]+(\.[[:upper:]]+)?' file
```

The output:

```
BRK.B
PFE
NOV
C
AAPL
MMM
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need something like:

`([A-Z.]+):\d`

The tickers will be stored on group 1

---

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/RQ8Ptu/1)

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
$ awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i ~ /[[:alnum:]]*%$/) {split($i,a,":"); gsub(/*/,"",a[1]);print a[1]}}' f
BRK.B
PFE
NOV
C
AAPL
MMM
```

Answer (score 0):

@try:

```
awk '/*|%|:/{gsub(/:.*/,"");sub(/\*/,"");print}' RS=" "    Input_file
```

making RS(record separator) as space. Then checking if any line is having (* or % or :) if yes then, globally substitute (:.*) to NULL in whole line, then substitute (*) string with NULL in current line. Then print the line of Input_file.